# How do I get a matplot lib plot to display?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm running all of this via Sublime Text and terminal:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Functional Plot
x_1 = np.linspace(0,5,10) #10 float from 0 to 5 
y_1 = x_1 ** 2 #Y values are squared x value 

plt.plot(x_1, y_1) #display plot
plt.title('Days Squared') #Add title
plt.xlabel('X label') 
plt.ylabel('Y label') 
plt.show()
```

In Terminal I get this: zsh: segmentation fault  python3 mplintro.py

And then an error message saying python shut down and do I want to restart it??

Comment: This is most likely an issue with your python/matplotlib installation. Do you know the versions that you are using for them? This code works using python v3.9.4 and matplotlib v3.4.2

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7.2 and MPL 3.1.3?

Comment: I also get a segmentation fault when running the same versions as you! Yay for reproducibility! Upgrading to at least `matplotlib==3.3.3` should fix the issue, there is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18953#issuecomment-750900672) that speculates about the source of the problem. As far as I can tell upgrading is the fix.